# ajenti web panel failed to load angular after install

Tags: angular, web, panel

after i install ajenti web admin i open my ip adress on port 8000 but i found white screen
i see in the inspector that ajenti failed to load angular and i have no more detail i did int foud a furom fo ajenti to ask the question please help

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Server Error)
all.js:2033 Plugin load error:
(anonymous) @ all.js:2033
all.js:2034  * /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ajenti_plugin_core/resources/build/all.js
(anonymous) @ all.js:2034
all.js:2035    ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at all.js:702
(anonymous) @ all.js:2035
all.js:2208 Plugin load error:
(anonymous) @ all.js:2208
all.js:2209  * /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ajenti_plugin_auth_users/resources/build/all.js
(anonymous) @ all.js:2209
all.js:2210    ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at all.js:2041
(anonymous) @ all.js:2210
all.js:2502 Plugin load error:
(anonymous) @ all.js:2502
all.js:2503  * /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ajenti_plugin_augeas/resources/build/all.js
(anonymous) @ all.js:2503
all.js:2504    ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at all.js:2216
(anonymous) @ all.js:2504
all.js:2824 Plugin load error:
(anonymous) @ all.js:2824
all.js:2825  * /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ajenti_plugin_dashboard/resources/build/all.js
(anonymous) @ all.js:2825
all.js:2826    ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at all.js:2510
(anonymous) @ all.js:2826
all.js:2969 Plugin load error:
(anonymous) @ all.js:2969
all.js:2970  * /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ajenti_plugin_datetime/resources/build/all.js
(anonymous) @ all.js:2970
all.js:2971    ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at all.js:2832
(anonymous) @ all.js:2971
all.js:3040 Plugin load error:
(anonymous) @ all.js:3040
all.js:3041  * /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ajenti_plugin_ace/resources/build/all.js
(anonymous) @ all.js:3041
all.js:3042    ReferenceError: angular is not defined
```

Comment: did you find any solution??

Comment: no not yet even in ajenty forum

Comment: Hmm looks like something wrong in front end any other cpanels you tried? thats free?